# dynamic programming task / counting problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am struggling with a dynamic programming task I cannot solve. I've found in a book a similar problem when you are asked to calculate the number of solutions and it says that this is a counting problem not optimization problem which is obvious. I want an advice how to deal with this kind of tasks and i want to know if there is a general approach to this. I want to know the recursive relation here and which are the subproblems. Here is the problem:

You are given n places to place your cubes. Minimum three consecutive cubes are considered as a figure. Figures are separated by minimum one place. You are asked to calculate all ways you can place the figures on the free places. Here is a solution for n = 7. Blue squares represent free places to place a cube and red ones are the cubes. Number of ways is equal to 17.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

@saeedn almost had it, but his recursive formula is not quite correct, as it has some missing cases and some double countings.

Let's examine the possibilities for the first place, either it's a space (single space), or there is a figure there. The length of the figure could be 3,4,...,n-1,n.

If it is less then `n`, we also need to add 'padding' before the next figure (to avoid double countings), so if we have a figure of 3 cubes, it has `f(n-4)` different possibilities (with the first 3 cells being cubes). An exception is for a figure of `n` nodes, because we cannot add a 'padding' after it.

Another possibility is a single space, and if there will be more spaces, the recursion will take care of it later on.

This gives us the following recursive formula:

```
f(0) = f(1) = f(2) = 1 (base)
f(n) = f(n-4) + f(n-5) + ... + f(1) + f(0) +   f(0)      + f(n-1)
         ^        ^             ^       ^       ^             ^
         3        4             n-2     n-1      n           space
       cubes    cubes          cubes    cubes   cubes
         +         +             +       +        +
        space    space         space    space   space
```

So, if we imply this formula to a DP algorithm, we'll get:

```
arr[n+1] = [0,0,...,0]
arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 1
for (int i = 3; i < n+1; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j <= i - 4; j++)  //f(n-4) + f(n-5) + ... + f(1) + f(0)
      arr[i] += arr[j]
   arr[i] += arr[0] // extra one f(0) for a shape with i cubes
   arr[i] += arr[i-1] // space
return arr[n]
```

Comment: Now i understand how this works. I have only one more question about this: How you figured out which will be the base cases here? And how you are sure that all this is correct? please explain that. Thanks

Comment: It's old and now i fully understand the solution except one thing: Why are we only calling f(n-1) for one space and not making figures of empty spaces? How are we sure we are not missing solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For finding recursion relation in these kind of problems, you should think of a possible placement, say at the start of your places, and see how you can see the rest of the places as a problem like the initial one, but with smaller size.

For example in this problem, starting from left, you can place a figure in place number 1, 2, ..., n-L (where L is the size of figure), and treat the rest of the spaces to the right of that figure (excluding one space for separation) as the same problem with smaller size.

If we want to formulate the recursion, we can write like this:

F(n) = sum [L=3 to n] (sum [p=0 to n-L] (F(n-p-L-1)))

where L iterates over figure sizes and p iterates over place of putting that figure (starting from left).

For more elaboration:

```
(putting figure of size of 3)
###---- (we spent 3 spaces and reserve one space for separator,
         thus we have n-4 spaces which can be filled in F(n-4) ways)
-###--- (putting the figure in next available space => F(n-5) for the rest)
...
----###

(now putting figure of size 4)
####--- (F(n-(4+1)) = F(n-5) ways for empty spaces)
...

(and so on)
```

Comment: I am almost certain you have duplicate counts there, as according to your solution (s,s,s,c,c,c) [s is space, c is cube] can be obtained by f(n-1)->f(n-1)->f(n-4) and f(n-2)->f(n-4). Am I wrong? please elaborate.

Comment: @amit Yes, you're right. Another obvious case is all empty case, which is counted by all combination of skipping. I'll update the answer to correct it.

Comment: There are another issue of missing counts, for f(0) (twice) for a figure with n-1 cubes and a figure with n cubes. I added an answer that covers everything (IMO).

Comment: @amit i don't fully understand the recursive relation. I started with this recently and i need in depth explanation. Can you explain me why you add f(n-4) + f(n-5) + ... and how you handle the free spaces? thank you very much

Comment: @overflowed are you asking about my answer or amit's answer?

Comment: @saeedn I was asking for amit's solution. It is not clear to me why he adds the solutions. Also, how he is sure that this gives the right solution? how to check it? I know i sound little boring but i still don't get it. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @overflowed If you have a question about his answer, you should comment on his answer and ask it from him. I know about mine. I updated my answer so it works. I tested it on a problem in Project Euler. I can give more explanation if you want.